# Using tag key to insert text and change the size of text in Web application

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I am making a basic online editing interface for coursework and i want to use keyboard events. The tab key should insert text, this works, but it should also reduce the size of the text on that line. When I use the getElementById, an error displays saying: Cannot read property 'style' of null. How do I go about this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>

<body>
<aside class="bar">
  <div id="heading-container"></div>
</aside>
  <div id="inputArea">
    <div id="bulletPoints" contenteditable="true">
      <div id="divList" contenteditable="true">
        <ul class="inputList">
          <li id="outlineList"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
     window.onload = () => {
     window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);

      function checkKeyPress(key){
         if (key.keyCode === 9){
         key.preventDefault();
         document.execCommand("insertText", true, "    ");
         document.getElementById("inputList").style.fontSize = "smaller";
        }
       }
     };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `inputList` is a class not an id, ie `class="inputList"` vs `id="inputList"`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
</head>

<body>
<aside class="bar">
  <div id="heading-container"></div>
</aside>
  <div id="inputArea">
    <div id="bulletPoints" contenteditable="true">
      <div id="divList" contenteditable="true">
        <ul class="inputList" id="inputList">
          <li id="outlineList"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
     window.onload = () => {
     window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPress);

      function checkKeyPress(key){
         if (key.keyCode === 9){
         key.preventDefault();
         document.execCommand("insertText", true, "    ");
         document.getElementById("inputList").style.fontSize = "smaller";
        }
       }
     };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You are missing you id as an attribute to your `ul`.